# ¿cómo generar todas las posibles coordenadas de una matriz de N dimensiones en Python?

Tags: python, array, matrices, numpy

El objetivo es poder tener una matriz con todas las posiciones de una matriz de N dimensiones que ingrese el usuario, el usuario solo me ingresa las dimensiones y yo debo imprimir las coordenadas, es decir si el usuario me ingresa [3, 2, 4] el algoritmo deberá imprimir todas las posibles coordenadas de ese arreglo, he intentado con itertools pero el mayor problema es que yo no sé que valor puede ser n y no sé como hacer esa generalización. se me ocurre un algoritmo recursivo pero me genera posiciones que no están en la matriz, realmente no se como hacerlo.

¿ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Numpy tiene algo que ya hace justo lo que quieres [`numpy.ndindex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html). Retorna un **iterador** con todos los posibles índices de acuerdo a las dimensiones pasadas como argumentos. Puedes iterar sobre el con un `for` por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

dims = (3, 2, 3)
for indice in np.ndindex(*dims):
    print(indice)
```

> ```
> (0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 1)
> (0, 0, 2)
> (0, 1, 0)
> (0, 1, 1)
> (0, 1, 2)
> (1, 0, 0)
> (1, 0, 1)
> (1, 0, 2)
> (1, 1, 0)
> (1, 1, 1)
> (1, 1, 2)
> (2, 0, 0)
> (2, 0, 1)
> (2, 0, 2)
> (2, 1, 0)
> (2, 1, 1)
> (2, 1, 2)
> ```

o crear un contenedor (ten cuidado con la memoria si el array tiene muchos elementos):

```
indices = list(np.ndindex(*dims))
```

Si te gusta complicarte la vida y pasar de lo que NumPy te ofrece hecho..., puedes conseguirlo con `itertools.product` como comentabas en la pregunta. Simplemente genera un iterable con los posibles indices de cada dimensión, puedes usar `range` para ello:

```
import itertools


dims = (3, 2, 3)
for indice in itertools.product(*(range(d) for d in dims)):
    print(indice)
```

Comment: Hola extraño, Te amo :D